# How to uncompress omni.ja on OSX?

Tags: macos, firefox, zip

Mozilla uses a zip-like approach for their omni.ja in Firefox/Thunderbird as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_%28formerly_omni.jar%29). In the same article they only list Windows tools for uncompressing.

Does anyone know a tool (optimally a command line tool) that can unzip their zip-like format on OSX?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish this as follows (from the command line).

1. `mkdir ~/Desktop/omni`
2. (from wherever you have omni.ja): 
   `unzip omni.ja -d ~/Desktop/omni/`

That inflated everything in the omni.ja file into the directory I had created.

OS X 10.8.4